# What does this c code row do? (const VAR = "string";)

Tags: c, string, variables

Stumbled on this row of c code but was unsure if it is valid or not. What does it do? What type will the variable have?

```
const VARNAME = "String of text";
```

Comment: Hope this [link1](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html), [link2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_using_constants.htm) helps you...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you encounter this little abomination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curiously, I wasn't expecting this to compile, but it does. However, compiler doesn't like it too much:

```
..\main.c:4:7: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'VARNAME'
..\main.c:4:17: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

So it does take *int* as default type, and thus VARNAME has a pointer value, since a string is a pointer (which later could be cast as *char**).

This works perfectly (on a Intel IA32 machine):

```
#include<stdio.h>

const VARNAME = "String of text";

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", (char*)VARNAME);
    return 0;
}
```

But I personally wouldn't use such implicit typing. As explained on the comments below:

> it's even dangerous since sizeof(int) might be smaller than
>   sizeof(char*)

Comment: In your environment yes, but I believe the 'VARNAME' is defined in the OP's code.

Comment: It's even dangerous since `sizeof(int)` might be smaller than `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: This might work perfectly on your box, but storing a pointer in an `int` has implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

What GCC tries to do is:

1. Make a constant `VARNAME` with the default type, that is `int`;
2. make this constant `int` contain a pointer to the character constant.

On my machine, it doesn't compile, probably because `int` is 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits wide.

```
a.c:1: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the definition of "VARNAME" and you will see. I would say something like "char*".